# How to use mod_rewrite and still show requested URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wish to have request for http://user1.domain.com :

- return the output from http://www.domain.com/site-client/site.php?site=user1
- AND user still see the URL 'http://user1.domain.com' in the browser

Right now I have the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Protect the htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/site-client/site.php?site=%1 [L]
```

The successfully calls the http://www.domain.com/site-client/site.php?site=user1  URL, but it shows it to the user.
How can I avoid this?

Comment: Are www. and user1. hosted on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `http://www.domain.com` part of yor `RewriteRule`'s target. It tells mod_rewrite that you want a 302 redirect. So your rule should look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site-client/site.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site-client/site.php?site=%1 [L]
```

EDIT: You'll also need a check to keep the rule from looping

Comment: I tried, but I am getting an error "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@domain.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: @tucson See the edit, needed to prevent the rules from looping